# WPF Converter getting weird value from Binding 

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have setup binding as follows

**XAML**

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToStringConverter}}" />
```

**C#: Showing what `Color` is**

```
public System.Windows.Media.Color Color
{
    get
    {
        var color = new HSLColor { Hue = this.Hue, Saturation = this.Saturation, Luminosity = this.Luminosity };
        string strColor = color.ToRGBString();
        return new System.Windows.Media.Color { 
            R = byte.Parse(strColor.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
            G = byte.Parse(strColor.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
            B = byte.Parse(strColor.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
        };
    }
    set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class ColorToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color color = (Color)value;
        return color.ToString();
    }
}
```

But my converter is getting `value` like

```
value = "{Name=0, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}"
```

I'd expect it to be a `System.Windows.Media.Color` why am I getting this?

Basically, I have 3 Silders for HSL values bound to `DependencyProperties`, each have a `PropertyChangedCallback` attached to them

```
new PropertyChangedCallback(HSLValuePropertyChanged)
```

It looks like

```
protected void HSLValueChanged()
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Color"));
}
```

Basically its purpose is to update controls bound to the dependency property `Color`. The idea is that `get` should run for property `Color` which creates a new color from HSL properties. The problem it seems is that the get does not run even when I change HSL values.

**UPDATE**

So I tried to return just `value` in the case of an exception, I got nothing in the textbox, so i did `value.toString()` got `Color [Empty]` all the time. What did I do wrong?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        Color color = (Color)value;
        return color.ToString();
    } catch (Exception) {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that calling `color.ToString()` generates the string `"{Name=0, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}"`?

Comment: @Steve Greatrex, I am not sure if toString() will automatically be called? Cos when I try to bind the textbox to Color without a converter, I get nothing, no such text at all, so I thought maybe I need a converter

Comment: @jiewmeng, If you omit the `ToString()` call when binding to a `TextBlock`, it will automatically be called.  If you put a breakpoint in your `Convert` method, is `value` what you would expect - an instance of `System.Windows.Media.Color` with the correct values?  If not, I'd suggest stepping through your `Color` property getter to see what it creates

Comment: @Steve Greatrex, whats strange is that get never gets run see update. And I always get a empty color

Comment: Looks like the value your converter gets is NULL (!?). Is the DataContext well-set?

Comment: @jiewmeng - agree with Benjamin Baumann - it sounds like your binding is not hitting your property accessor.  I would try `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />` to check what your `DataContext` is set to

Comment: Yes data context sets ok as I have text box bound to other properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the ColorDependencyProperty.
If so, I think the binding may never actually go trough the accessors (get/set) ...

You should set the new color (in the dependencyProperty via the setvalue method) on each of your H/S/L properties change call back...

I hope i am clear :-)

Comment: +1. I don't think you can compute the value in the dependency property attachement process. You are about to create a dependency property which can be set but whose value always depends on other properties (so the set is uneffective). My Question is why do you need this as a dependency property instead of a "basic" property?

Comment: So I guess I should do something like [this]http://pastebin.com/S3L8VAaC() instead? It works tho. But I still don't understand why I can't just raise property change, that should cause controls to get the new color from the `get`?

Comment: @jiewmeng : because the get accessor is never called from the binding. Instead, it will use the GetValue method of the Dependency property...

Answer (score 1):

When bound on a DependencyProperty, bindings dont use property getters to obtain values, so, all the code you put in the `Color` property getter is skipped as far as bindings are concerned.

Stick to defining your getters as `get { return (XXX)GetValue(MyProperty); }` and find another way around.

Comment: -1 Bindings can use property getters - you are referring to `DependencyProperty` backed properties, which are not applicable here

Comment: It's pretty the same that what I was saying... And I agree with you: the binding will not use the get accessor.

Comment: @Steve He **is** talking about a DependencyProperty... Look at the code : `set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }`

Comment: you are right - my mistake, though I can't remove the downvote unless you edit the answer.  Worth noting, however, that your general statement is incorrect - Bindings do no necessarily use dependency properties